# Using reflection get a static private hashmap in java

Tags: java, reflection, hashmap

I'm trying to find a way to extract a HashMap from a private static field within another class via Java.

eg.

Inside FooClass there is a static field that looks like this:

```
private Map entityRenderMap;
```

Then in its construct it has:

`entityRenderMap = new HashMap();`

How do you get the values within entityRenderMap via Reflection in Java? I've tried this but get errors:

```
cl = RenderManager.class.getDeclaredField("entityRenderMap");
        cl.setAccessible(true);
        Object foo = cl.get(this.entityRenderMap);
        Mod.log(cl.getName());
```

The error I get is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.util.Map field RenderManager.entityRenderMap to java.util.HashMap
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(Unknown Source
```

Comment: your entityRenderMap is not static.

Comment: You say that the field is static, but the declaration shows that it's not. And what is the type of `this.entityRenderMap` that is passed to `cl.get()`?

Comment: I just realised that the field is not static after all.... I totally screwed the pooch then.. (long night).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your code doesn't match your explanation. Is it really a static field or is it not (your code says it's not)?

If it is static, you should pass `null` as argument to `cl.get()` (you don't need an instance to access static members).

However, I suspect that your field is actually not static, and your passing the wrong instance to `cl.get()`. The JavaDocs to [`Field.get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) state it would throw an `IllegalArgumentException` in this case. You need to pass a `RenderManager` instance to this method. Your code looks like your passing a `Map` (the `entityRenderMap`).

And last, is this code inside your `RenderManager` class? I suspect this, because your accessing a field with `this` with the same name as the field you want to set. In this case, don't use reflection at all!

Comment: Yes sorry it wasnt static after all for some reason (fatigue maybe) i was running my head into a wall on "Why wont this work!" only to realise it was a human bug not software :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you certain it is a static field. The javadoc of the `get` method clearly states:

> If the underlying field is a static field, the obj argument is ignored; it may be null.
>
> Otherwise, the underlying field is an instance field. If the specified obj argument is null, the method throws a NullPointerException. If the specified object is not an instance of the class or interface declaring the underlying field, the method throws an IllegalArgumentException.

So with a static field you would not get the `IllegalArgumentException` since the parameter is ignored. Further, the code you posted shows it is not a static field but a regular field (since it lacks the word `static`, and its initialized in the constructor).

If you want to access the field of a certain instance `A`, you should pass that instance `A` to the `Field#get` method, and not the `A.field` as you are trying to do with your `cl.get(this.entityRenderMap)` call.

You can take a look at [this tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/fields.html) for some examples

Answer (score 2):

If the field is really static, you should pass `null` as an argument to `cl.get()`.

If the field is not static, then you must pass the instance of `FooClass` which you want to get the field value from:

```
FooClass fc = new FooClass(); // or whatever, provided that fc is a FooClass instance
Object foo = cl.get(fc);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming `cl` is a [java.lang.reflect.Field](http://www.kiwidoc.com/java/l/p/java/j2se/1.6/p/java.lang.reflect/c/Field). The documentation states that Fields' [get-method](http://www.kiwidoc.com/java/l/p/java/j2se/1.6/p/java.lang.reflect/c/Field#get%28Ljava/lang/Object;%29) will throw:

> IllegalArgumentException - if the specified object is not an instance
>   of the class or interface declaring the underlying field (or a
>   subclass or implementor thereof).

You should be passing the `RenderManager`-object to the get-method instead of the field (unless it's static, which it is not according to your example).

Answer (score 0):

```
vim Test.java
    import java.util.*;
    import com.dp4j.*;

class FooClass{

private static Map entityRenderMap;

FooClass(){
entityRenderMap = new HashMap();
}

}

public class Test{
@Reflect
public static void main(String... args){

Map reflectEntityMap = FooClass.entityRenderMap;
}
}


javac -cp ~/ws/dp4j/dp4j.jar -Averbose=true Test.java
Test.java:16: Note: 
import java.util.*;
import com.dp4j.*;

class FooClass {
    private static Map entityRenderMap;

    FooClass() {
        entityRenderMap = new HashMap();
    }
}
public class Test {

    public Test() {
        super();
    }

    @Reflect()
    public static void main(String... args) throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException, java.lang.NoSuchFieldException, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException, java.lang.IllegalAccessException {
        java.lang.reflect.Field entityRenderMapField = null;
        entityRenderMapField = Class.forName("FooClass").getDeclaredField("entityRenderMap");
        entityRenderMapField.setAccessible(true);
        Map reflectEntityMap;
        reflectEntityMap = (.java.util.Map)entityRenderMapField.get("");
    }
}
```